# Updating mysql table information if 24 hours have passed

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I've got a table named charitydonations that includes entries which, along other data, they also contain one named datecreated, which is a value of this format: 2016-09-12 11:10:37 and a random hash that comes from md5(rand() . microtime()); in 'hash' value of every entry.

I'm tying to implement a way of having this hash reseted based on the fact that 24 hours have passed since datecreated and based on the current time.

My logic is:

1. Get all charitydonations.
2. Check if datecreated is older then 1 day
3. If is older, generate new token like: md5(rand() . microtime());
4. Update donations token in database based on the donation id, which is the unique identifier.

I guess I'm really close but unfortunately, I haven't achieved to make it work.

Here is my code so far:

```
$charitydonations = $this->db->get('tbldonations')->result_array();

foreach($donations as $donation)
{
    if (strtotime($item->date) <= strtotime('-1 day'))
    {

        // not really sure how to mark it as $older

    }

    if ($older)
    {
        $new_hash = md5(rand() . microtime());
        $this->db->where('id', $invoice['id']);
        $this->db->update('tbldonations', array(
            'hash' => $new_hash
        ));
    }
}
```

If someone can help me, I'd be more than thankful guys.

Comment: Might be helpful to others attempting to assist you if they knew in what way it doesn't work. Do you get errors ... does it give you undesirable behaviour / results?

Comment: Im not even sure of the way its being implemented, thats why I added this part of code there: // not really sure how to mark it as $older